# Get the count of a specific column with join query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables, `products` and `stocks`. Each product has a stock record foreign key `product_id` in the `stocks` table. Each stock record has a `quantity` column.

**Fields in the stocks table look like,**

```
id | product_id | color_id | quantity
```

**In brief:** 1 product can have many stock records. I'm trying to get the product and its total count in the quantity column of stock records. Imagine **product A (product id is 1)** has 3 stock records in the stocks table like this,

```
id | product_id | color_id | quantity
1  |     1      |     3    |   10
2  |     1      |     4    |   20
3  |     1      |     2    |   40
```

Here for **product A** the total of quantity column in the stocks table is `10 + 20 + 40 = 70`. I'm expecting to return this `70` and the product record.

**Here is my code. I have no idea how to get that,**

```
      return DB::table('products')
        ->join('stocks', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')
        ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Show us how `stock` table looks like

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Made it more meaningful

Comment: `DB::table('products')
->join('stocks', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')
->select('products.*', DB::raw("sum(stocks.quantity) as quantity"))
->groupBy('stocks.product_id')
->get();`

Can try this ?

Comment: @MishenThakshana updated the answer. It will fix the error.  :)

Comment: @MishenThakshana worked right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your joins are correct use `sum()` with `groupBy()` clause

```
->select(DB::raw("SUM(stocks.quantity) as stocks_quantity"))
->groupBy('stocks.product_id') # or ->groupBy('products.id')
```

---

```
DB::table('products')
    ->join('stocks', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')
    ->select(DB::raw("SUM(stocks.quantity) as stocks_quantity"))
    ->groupBy('products.id') #or groupBy('stocks.product_id')
    ->paginate(5);
```

---

**Edit 01**

```
DB::table('products')
    ->join('stocks', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')
    ->select('products.*')
    ->selectRaw("SUM(stocks.quantity) as stocks_quantity")
    ->groupBy('stocks.product_id')
    ->get(5);
```

---

**Edit 02**

> add `'products.id'` in select

```
DB::table('products')
    ->leftjoin('stocks', 'products.id', '=', 'stocks.product_id')
    ->select('products.id','products.*')
    ->selectRaw("SUM(stocks.quantity) as stocks_quantity")
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->get(5);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248628/discussion-on-answer-by-abdulla-nilam-get-the-count-of-a-specific-column-with-jo).